# Differential of the multiplication and inverse maps on a Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, lie-groups

I'm trying to solve the following two problems:

> Let $G$ be a Lie group with multiplication map $\mu\colon G\times G\to G$, and let $\ell_a\colon G\to G$ and $r_b\colon G\to G$ be left and right multiplication by $a$ and $b$ in $G$, respectively.
>       Show that the differential of $\mu$ at $(a,b)\in G\times G$ is
>       $$
> \mu_{*, (a,b)}(X_a,Y_b)
> = (r_b)_*(X_a) + (\ell_a)_*(Y_b)
> \quad \text{for } X_a\in T_aG,\ Y_b\in T_bG.
> $$

and

> Let $G$ be a Lie group with multiplication map $\mu\colon G\times G\to G$, inverse map $\iota\colon G\to G$, and identity element $e$.
>       Show that the differential of the inverse map at $a\in G$,
>       $$
> \iota_{*,a} \colon T_aG \to T_{a^{-1}}G,
> $$
>       is given by
>       $$
> \iota_{*,a}(Y_a) = -(r_{a^{-1}})_* (\ell_{a^{-1}})_* Y_a,
> $$
>       where $(r_{a^{-1}})_* = (r_{a^{-1}})_{*,e}$ and $(\ell_{a^{-1}})_* = (\ell_{a^{-1}})_{*,a}$.

I am wondering if I should try to find curves through these points, or just apply either side to functions in $C^\infty(G)$? It looks like there are some questions on here about the differential of [multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799211/lie-group-differential-of-multiplication-map) and [inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904231/differential-of-the-inversion-of-lie-group?lq=1) at the identity, but I'm trying to evaluate these at arbitrary points... the author (Tu) talks about the matrix exponential in this section but should I use that here? These Lie groups don't necessarily contain matrices.

Answer (score 24):

One of Tu's previous exercises, ex. $8.7^*$ shows that for $M,N$ manifolds, by defining $\pi_1:M\times N\to M$ and $\pi_2: M\times N \to N$, one can show for $(p,q)\in M\times N$ that $$\pi_{1*}\times\pi_{2*}:T_{(p,q)}(M\times N)\to T_pM\times T_qN$$
is an isomorphism. Also $T_pM\times T_qN\cong T_pM \oplus T_q N$, which shows up in other texts like Lee.

The proof of this is actually in the back of Tu's book, which I assume you have or had, but I can supply it if requested.

Anyway the key is to use this and his proposition $8.17$ which shows how to compute differentials with curves. The usefulness of the above exercise is that we can write a tangent vector at $(a,b)$ as $(X_a,Y_b)$ rather than just something like $v$, as $T_{(a,b)}(G\times G)\cong T_aG\times T_bG$

For $Q1$ we use first use that $\mu_*$ is a linear map from $T_a G\times T_b G \to T_{\mu(a,b)}G$ so that $$\mu_{*,(a,b)}(X_a,Y_b)=\mu_{*,(a,b)}(X_a,0)+\mu_{*,(a,b)}(0,Y_b)$$

Then by proposition $8.17$ we can compute these with curves. For $\mu_{*,(a,b)}(X_a,0)$ consider a curve $c(t)$ in $G$ such that $c(0)=a$ and $c'(0)=X_a$, then we define a curve $\gamma(t)$ in $G\times G$ by $\gamma(t)=(c(t),b)$. Thus $$\mu_{*,(a,b)}(X_a,0)=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_0 \mu\circ\gamma=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_0 \mu(c(t),b)$$

On the other hand consider the right multiplication map by $r_b:G\to G$ by $a\mapsto \mu(a,b)$. Then $(r_{b})_*:T_a(G)\to T_{\mu(a,b)}G$. Again we can compute this by the same curve $c(t)$ so that $(r_{b})_*(X_a)=\dfrac{d}{dt}\bigg|_0 r_b\circ c$. We can then identify this with the above, since

$$(r_{b})_*(X_a)=\dfrac{d}{dt}\bigg|_0 r_b\circ c= \dfrac{d}{dt}\bigg|_0 \mu(c(t),b) $$

A similar argument with left multiplication shows that:

> $$\mu_{*,(a,b)}(X_a,Y_b)=\mu_{*,(a,b)}(X_a,0)+\mu_{*,(a,b)}(0,Y_b)=(r_{b})_*(X_a)+(l_{a})_*(Y_b)$$

I will update when I have question $2$ worked out nicely.

**Update**(*long overdue - apologies*)

Given $\iota:G\to G$, $\iota(a)=a^{-1}$, and $\iota_{*,a}:T_a G\to T_{a^{-1}}G$, we are asked to show that $$\iota_{*,a}(Y_a)=-(r_{a^{-1}})(l_{a^{-1}})_*(Y_a)$$
where $(l_{a^{-1}})_*=(l_{a^{-1}})_{*,a}$ and $(r_{a^{-1}})_*=(r_{a^{-1}})_{*,e}$. Since we know what the answer is supposed to look like and we're reminded that in problem $8.8(b)^\&$ we proved that $\iota_{*,e}(X_e)=-X_e$, the trick is to notice that $\iota=r_{a^{-1}}\circ\iota\circ l_{a^{-1}}$ via checking that (using juxtaposition instead of writing the $\mu$'s) $$r_{a^{-1}}\circ\iota\circ l_{a^{-1}}(x)=(a^{-1}x)^{-1}a^{-1}=x^{-1}aa^{-1}=x^{-1}=\iota(x)$$

So using this and the chain rule we have that

$$\iota_{*,a}(Y_a)=(r_{a^{-1}})_{*,e}\circ\iota_{*,e}\circ (l_{a^{-1}})_{*,a}(Y_a)$$

Calling for convenience $X_e:=(l_{a^{-1}})_{*,a}(Y_a)$, and using $\iota_{*,e}(X_e)=-X_e$ and linearity of the differential/pushforward maps we have

> $$\iota_{*,a}(Y_a)=(r_{a^{-1}})_{*,e}(-X_e)=-(r_{a^{-1}})_{*,e}(l_{a^{-1}})_{*,a}(Y_a)$$

---

---

$^\&$Proof of $8.8(b)$ for completeness sake:

The pushforward $\iota_{*,e}:T_e G\to T_e G$ of the inverse map can be computed as in the first question by choosing a curve. If we want to calculate $\iota_{*,e}(X_e)$, choose a curve $c(t)$ in $G$ such that $c(0)=e$ and $c'(0)=X_e$.

We know that $\iota_{*,e}(X_e)=\frac{d}{dt}\big|_0 \iota\circ c$ which we call $Y_e$ for convenience, that is set $Y_e=\iota_{*,e}(X_e)$. The hint given says to use that $\mu(c(t),\iota\circ c(t))=e$. This can be seen as a composition of the maps $\mu \circ \left(c\times (\iota\circ c)\right)$, which is a constant map from some (say) open interval $(a,b)\times (a,b)\to G\times G$.

Using that the differential of a constant map is the zero map, then $$\mu_{*,(e,e)}(X_e,Y_e)=\mu_{*,(e,e)}(X_e,0)+\mu_{*,(e,e)}(0,Y_e)=0$$

We just need that $\mu_{*,(e,e)}(X_e,0)=X_e$ and $\mu_{*,(e,e)}(0,Y_e)=Y_e$, from $8.8(a)$, which essentially follows similarly to problem 1, defining curves $\gamma(t)=(c(t),e)$ and $\tilde{\gamma}(t)=(e,\iota\circ c(t))$ $$\mu_{*,(e,e)}(X_e,0)=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_0 \mu\circ \gamma=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_0 \mu(c(t),e)=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_0 c=X_e$$

and

$$\mu_{*,(e,e)}(0,Y_e)=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_0 \mu\circ \tilde{\gamma}=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_0 \mu(e,\iota\circ c(t))=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_0 \iota\circ c=Y_e$$

so we have that $X_e+Y_e=0$ and so that

> $$\iota_{*,e}(X_e)=Y_e=-X_e$$

Comment: thanks very useful.
I am trying to find the same result for exercize 2 using a slightly different approach but got stuck.
I want to use a curve $c(t)$ in G whose value at $t_0$ is $a$ and whose differential is $X_a$ and use again the fact that $\mu(c(t),\iota\circ c(t))$ is the constant map. I then apply the result from exercise 1, getting $(r_{a^-1})_{*,a}X_a+(l_{a})_{*,a}\iota_{*,a}(X_a)=0$ and then just $\iota_{*,a}(X_a)=((l_a)_{*,a})^{-1}(r_{a^-1})_{*,a}X_a$. Where am I wrong? thanks

Comment: actually  $\iota_{*,a}(X_a)=-((l_a)_{*,a})^{-1}(r_{a^-1})_{*,a}X_a$. also, what is the point of the subscript $e$ opposed to $a$ for the differential of the right and left multiplication? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here $\exp(tX)$ is a curve at identity $e$ whose tangent is $X\in
T_eG$

(1) $$\frac{d}{dt} \mu (a,\exp(tY)b)= \frac{d}{dt} a(\exp (tY)b)=dl_a\
  Y_b$$

$$\frac{d}{dt} \mu (a\exp(tX), b)= \frac{d}{dt} (a
   \exp (tX)) b=dr_b\
  X_a$$
Hence $$ dl_a\ Y_b + dr_b\ X_a= d\mu\ \{ \frac{d}{dt} (a,\exp(tY)b)
+ \frac{d}{dt} (a\exp (tX),b) \} =d\mu \{ (0,Y_b) + (X_a,0) \} $$

(2) $$ 0= \frac{d}{dt}\mu
 (a\exp (tY), [\exp (tY)]^{-1} a^{-1} ) =\frac{d}{dt}\mu
 (a\exp (tY),  i (a \exp (tY) )  ) =    dr_{a^{-1}} Y_a +
 dl_a \ di_a\ Y_a $$
so that $$ di_a \ Y_a= - (dl_a)^{-1} dr_{a^{-1}}\ Y_a $$

( We will show that $(dl_a)^{-1}=dl_{a^{-1}} $ : $
 dl_{a^{-1}} dl_a\ X = \frac{d}{dt} \exp (tX) =X  $)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question. Here is my elementary solution, which does not make use of curves.

We start with a theorem:

> **Theorem**: Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds. Let $p\in M$ and $q\in N$. Let  $$\pi_1: M\times N \to M, \quad \pi_2: M\times N \to
>  N$$ be the projection maps. Let $$\eta_1: M\to M\times N: m\mapsto
>  (m,q), \quad \eta_2: N \to M\times N: n \mapsto (p,n)$$ be the
> inclusion maps. We have canonical maps $$\varphi: T_{(p,q)}(M\times N)
>  \to T_p M \times T_q N: z \mapsto ((\pi_1)_{*, (p,q)}(z), (\pi_2)_{*,
>  (p,q)}(z))$$ $$\psi: T_p M\times  T_q N\to T_{(p,q)}(M\times N): (x,y)
>  \mapsto (\eta_1)_{*,p}(x)+ (\eta_2)_{*,q}(y).$$ Then $\varphi$ and
> $\psi$ are inverse to each other.

**Proof**: Just calculate a composition using the chain rule.

> **Corollary**: Let $G$ be a Lie group. If $p,q\in G$, and $l_p: G \to G$ is left multiplication and $r_q: G \to G$ is right multiplication
> in $G$ and $\kappa = \mu_{*,(p,q)}\circ \psi$ is the composition $$T_p
>  G \times T_q G \cong T_{(p,q)}(G\times G)\to T_{pq}(G)$$ then
> $$\kappa(X_p, X_q) = (r_q)_{*,p}(X_p) + (l_p)_{*,q}(Y_p).$$ In
> particular, taking $p=q=e$ yields $\kappa(X_e, Y_e) = X_e + Y_e.$

**Proof**: Note that $\mu \circ \eta_1 = r_q, \mu \circ \eta_2 = l_p$. Hence,
$$\kappa(X_p, X_q) = \mu_{*,(p,q)}((\eta_1)_{*,p}(X_p) + (\eta_2)_{*,q}(X_q))= (r_q)_{*,p}(X_p) + (l_p)_{*,q}(X_q)$$
by the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof for question (b):
Define $K=id\times \ell:G\rightarrow G\times G$, where "$id$" is the identity. Then $F=\mu\circ K$ is a constant map towards unit. Hence,
$\forall X_{e}\in T_{e}G$:
\begin{align}
(\mathrm{d}F)_{e}(X_{e})&=\mathrm{d}\mu_{(e,e)}\circ (\mathrm{d}K)_{e}(X_{e})\\
&=\mathrm{d}\mu_{(e,e)}((X_{e},(\mathrm{d}\ell)_{e}(X_{e})))\\
&=X_{e}+(\mathrm{d}\ell)_{e}(X_{e})=0
\end{align}
The result follows.

Comment: What is $i\text{d}_e(X)$? And why redefine all the notation from the original problem?

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo. Actually, I mean $(di)_{e}(X_{e})$. And I have adapt my notations to the orginal problem now.