# How to show that the inversion map is a anti-Poisson map?

Tags: lie-groups, quantum-groups, poisson-geometry

Let $G$ be a Poisson-Lie group and the inversion map $i:G\to G$ defined by
$$
g\mapsto g^{-1}.
$$
How to show that the inversion map is anti-Poisson, i.e., $\{f\circ i, g\circ i\}(x) = -\{f, g\}(x^{-1})$?

Also, I wonder what's the codomain of the Poisson bracket $\{\cdot, \cdot\}$ here? I understand that it takes elements $f,\;g\in C^\infty(G)$. Also, what does it mean to say $\{f,g\}(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a bit long because it requires some intermediate results from Poisson geometry. Although these results are not very complicated, I decided to recall all the necessary background and give an answer to this post so that it does not stay incomplete. In case one has some basic background in differential and Poisson geometry, they could jump directly to the third part.

---

#### Part 1: Basics on Poisson structures

To answer the simpler of your questions, the ***codomain*** of the Poisson bracket is ***the space of smooth functions*** of the manifold. More precisely, a Poisson bracket $\{\cdot\,,\cdot\}$ on a manifold $M$ is a map $\{\cdot\,,\cdot\}:C^\infty(M)\times C^\infty(M)\to C^\infty(M)$ satisfying the following three conditions:

1. Anti-symmetry: $\{f,g\}=-\{g,f\}$
2. Jacobi identity: $\{f,\{g,h\}\}=\{\{f,g\},h\}+\{g,\{f,h\}\}$
3. Leibniz identity: $\{f,gh\}=\{f,g\}h+g\{f,h\}$

for all $f,g,h\in C^\infty(M)$. Equivalently, a Poisson structure on $M$ is given by a bivector field $\pi\in\Gamma(\wedge^2TM)$ that satisfies the equation $[\pi,\pi]=0$; here, $[\cdot\,,\cdot]$ denotes the Schouten bracket on the space of multivector fields $\Gamma(\wedge TM)$. This description will be needed in the next part. Note that in this setting, a Poisson morphism is a smooth map between two Poisson manifolds $\phi:(M_1,\pi_1)\to(M_2,\pi_2)$ such that $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are $\phi$-related, i.e. $\phi_*\pi_1=\pi_2$.

Given two Poisson manifolds $(M_1,\pi_1)$ and $(M_2,\pi_2)$ the product manifold $M_1\times M_2$ inherits a Poisson bivector $\pi$ given point-wise by $\pi_{(p,q)} = (\wedge^2T_pi^1_q)(\pi_{1,p}) + (\wedge^2T_qi^2_p)(\pi_{2,q})$ for $(p,q)\in M_1\times M_2$, where the maps $i^1,i^2$ are the following collections of inclusions
$$ i^1_q:M_1\to M_1\times M_2;\ p\mapsto (p,q)\ \text{for a } \textbf{fixed } q\in M_2 $$
$$ i^2_p:M_2\to M_1\times M_2;\ q\mapsto (p,q)\ \text{for a } \textbf{fixed } p\in M_1. $$

#### Part 2: Basics on Poisson-Lie groups

A Poisson-Lie group is a Lie group $G$ equipped with a bivector field $\pi\in\Gamma(\wedge^2TG)$ such that the multiplication map $\mu:G\times G\to G$ is a Poisson map, where $G\times G$ is endowed with the product Poisson structure $\Pi\in\Gamma(\wedge^2T(G\times G))$ induced by $\pi$ on $G$. According to the first part, this translates to $\mu_*\Pi = \pi$.

**Proposition 1.** The compatibility of $\pi$ with the Lie group structure is equivalent to
$$ \pi_{gh} = (\wedge^2T_gR_h)(\pi_g) + (\wedge^2T_hL_g)(\pi_h),\ \text{for all } g,h\in G, $$
where $R_h$ and $L_g$ denote the right and left multiplication by $h$ and $g$, respectively.

*Proof.* Using the identities $\mu\circ i^1_h=R_h$ and $\mu\circ i^2_g=L_g$ we compute
$$ \wedge^2T_{(g,h)}\mu (\Pi_{(g,h)}) = \wedge^2T_{(g,h)}\mu(\wedge^2T_gi^1_h(\pi_g)) + \wedge^2T_{(g,h)}\mu(\wedge^2T_hi^2_g(\pi_h)) = \wedge^2T_gR_h(\pi_g) + \wedge^2T_hL_g(\pi_h). $$

**Lemma 2.** The Poisson structure of a Poisson-Lie group vanishes at the identity.

*Proof.* Substituting $e$ for $g$ and $h$ in the equation of Proposition 2 yields $\pi_e = \pi_e + \pi_e$ and hence $\pi_e = 0$.

#### Part 3: Inversion of a Poisson-Lie group is anti-Poisson

We prove the equivalent statement that the inverse map is a Poisson map between $(G,\pi)$ and $(G,-\pi)$. Let $g\in G$ and substitute $h$ with $g^{-1}$ in the equation of Proposition 1 above. So we have
$$ 0 = \pi_e = \wedge^2T_gR_{g^{-1}}(\pi_g) + \wedge^2T_{g^{-1}}L_g(\pi_{g^{-1}}). $$
Using now that $T_g \iota = -T_eL_{g^{-1}}\circ T_gR_{g^{-1}}$, we compute
$$ \wedge^2T_g\iota(\pi_g) =  \wedge^2T_eL_{g^{-1}}(\wedge^2T_gR_{g^{-1}}(\pi_g)) = - \wedge^2T_eL_{g^{-1}}(\wedge^2T_{g^{-1}}L_g(\pi_{g^{-1}})) = - \wedge^2T_{g^{-1}}\operatorname{id}_G(\pi_{g^{-1}}) = - \pi_{g^{-1}}$$
which proves the claim.

Comment: I don't understand why the following equality holds $:$ $$(d_{(g,h)} \mu \otimes d_{(g,h)} \mu) (\Pi_{(g,h)}) = (d_{(g,h)} \mu \otimes d_{(g,h)} \mu) ((d_{g} i_{h}^{1} \otimes d_{g} i _{h}^{1}) (\pi_{g})) + (d_{(g,h)} \mu \otimes d_{(g,h)} \mu) ((d_{h} i_{g}^{2} \otimes d_{h} i _{g}^{2}) (\pi_{h})).$$

Comment: Right above the header of Part 2, I explain how to get the Poisson bivector of the product manifold point-wise, i.e. $\pi_{(p,q)} = (\wedge^2T_pi^1_q)(\pi_{1,p}) + (\wedge^2T_qi^2_p)(\pi_{2,q})$. This gives the equality you're referring to.

Comment: How to show that $$T_{g} \iota = - T_{e} L_{g^{-1}} \circ T_{g} R_{g^{-1}}?$$ By chain rule the RHS becomes $-T_{g} (L_{g^{-1}} \circ R_{g^{-1}}).$ So for any $f \in C^{\infty} (G)$ and for any $X_{g} \in T_{g} G$ we need to show that $$X_{g} (f \circ \iota) = - X_{g} (f \circ L_{g^{-1}} \circ R_{g^{-1}}).$$

Comment: @AnilBagchi. This is discussed in detail here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740179/differential-of-the-multiplication-and-inverse-maps-on-a-lie-group